# How to make pizza as good as original italian pizza?

Tags: flavor, pizza, italian-cuisine, tasting

I love pizza and I tried few times with the recipes I found on the internet. It didn't taste like pizza I get from italian pizza vendors. Also I've tried few times some of the local pizza shops, including Pizza hut and Domino's Pizza. neither of those pizzas are even near as good as italian vendor's pizzas.

Why is that?

How can I make pizza at home just like italian vendor's original pizza?

Comment: Your question, as phrased, is far too broad for us to answer. What specific qualities of pizza (an item with a wide variety of recipes) are you trying to emulate. Are you going for New York or Chicago style? What have you already tried and how did it fall short?

Comment: How do you make your pizza, is your oven hot enough ? Are your ingredients "good" enough ?

Comment: Yes, we really need details about the pizza you're trying to replicate. As-is, people are forced to guess, and indeed, you already have a pretty generic answer that may or may not address your actual issues.

Comment: There are probably as many varieties of Italian pizza (if you are referring to vendors actually from Italy) as there are American ones. Even if you're going for a generic, Americanized version of pizza, Pizza Hut (unless you like a pound of salt per pizza) and, God forbid, Dominos is only going to be disappointing.  There's a reason why Dominos and Pappa John's target each other in commercials when fighting for the claim of America's Second-Worst pizza chain.

Comment: Sorry If my question is not good enough. I just need to find a better pizza other than pizza hut and dominos. where I live (not in US), those two are the main stream pizza vendors. I've tasted pizza few times from small italian shops, and those were much better, crust, sauce, ingredients, taste... everything. Pizza from those mainstream vendors are like just half baked cheese bread with a lot of salt.. That ain't pizza.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet agree with you. those two are main vendors where I live. their pizza tastes like half baked cheese bread with too much salt. that aint what pizza should taste like, right?  I found few italian shops on my travels that have good pizza. but they are located far far away from where I live.

Comment: What do you recall about pizza that you like?  Thick, chewy crust? Thin crust that's crisped on the bottom. A deep, rich, strong tomato sauce or something a bit closer to "fresh?" Or a Chicago-style deep dish with a buttery, biscut-like crust, deep, straight sides, toppings under/in the cheese with sauce on top?  If you put in those kinds of details, then maybe your question can be re-opened. If you're looking for the classic NY-style (think crust) or the Chicago-style I can refer you to very specific recipes and methods that work very well, even if you have already selected a best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How can I make pizza at home just like italian vendor's original pizza?"

Have a really powerful oven that can safely and consistently go up to 900F; use a pizza stone, use good dough, use fresh ingredients for the sauce, use good cheese and meats.

=====

Big pizza chains have standardized their recipes, processes and equipments (ovens) so they will (not always) try to find the easiest way to prepare a pizza so that the staff training costs (and operational costs) stay as low as possible.

They will prepare "generic" pizzas, sometimes they are good, sometimes they are bad, it all depends on our personal taste.

Small pizza shop will have a more "relaxed" approach to making pizza, they will have a better hands-on on the recipes, process and equipments, maybe they invested in a wood burning oven or a gas oven or a high-performance electric oven.

For example, in the best situation , the small pizza box will make sauce with the freshest in-season tomatoes (and can/freeze for the rest of the year), will buy better cheese and other ingredients and prepare the pizza dough and adapt it to the day's temperature and humidity.

They will bake the pizza and check with their eyes and nose instead of a timer.

Comment: Some modern ovens have a "pizza" mode, so it might be worth taking a look at your oven manual for the recommended mode for pizzas.

Comment: Most home ovens won't go to 900 degrees, and it's really not necessary. You just have to heat the stone/tiles/whatever up for a bit longer, I'd imagine.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet And if it's the slight burning of the cheese that you really want, you can just finish the pizza by broiling it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I use the very top rack of the oven to put my pizza tiles on, so the roof of the oven serves to reflect some of that heat back, more directly than from a lower level, which is basically the same function that you are talking about.

Comment: I am not pretending to know the recipe of an Italian pizza as I think although simple there are many pretending to know. Pizza: 350 g flour 160 g acqua, 40 g milk ,9 g salt,10 beer yeast 40 olive oil. Asked a friend that worked in a bakery and made wonderful pizza even at home. Keep it not overly thin. Home oven style worth of a try. Enjoy. From Italy.